# Magento unable to apply catalog rule

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

After migrating from Magento Professional to Magento Community, I have encountered an issue when attempting to run the "Apply Rules" function inside of Promotions >> Catalog Price Rules.

The exact message I receive is as follows:

"Unable to apply rules. Invalid website code requested: Array"

Has anyone seen this before? I can't seem to find /any/ information on the error.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: paste screen shot from the catalog price rule ?

Comment: Sure: http://i.imgur.com/QbsWGQn.png

Comment: I also noticed that this error only happens when I set a rule to be "Active." If all rules are inactive, and I click apply, the only message received is "Unable to apply rules."

Comment: because if the rule is not active it wont be applied even you clicked apply !! its price rule ( this means it will change the prices etc.. )

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information. So I guess the only issue is the "Invalid website code" error, which I can't seem to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

In Model App.php

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
public function getWebsite($id=null)
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $id = $this->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    } elseif ($id instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Website) {
        return $id;
    } elseif ($id === true) {
        return $this->_website;
    }

    if (empty($this->_websites[$id])) {
        $website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $website->load($id);
            if (!$website->hasWebsiteId()) {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid website id requested.');
            }
        } elseif (is_string($id)) {
            $websiteConfig = $this->_config->getNode('websites/'.$id);
            if (!$websiteConfig) {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid website code requested: '.$id);
            }
            $website->loadConfig($id);
        }
        $this->_websites[$website->getWebsiteId()] = $website;
        $this->_websites[$website->getCode()] = $website;
    }
    return $this->_websites[$id];
}
```

if you see the line that throw exception Invalid website code requested :$id

This is the exception happen in your case and its because the Price rule assigned to website not exist or wrong id or something related to this.

Try to delete the rule and adding it again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have deleted all rules, and added a test rule, with a 0% discount.  However, I receive the same error when I try to apply it.

Comment: Get all your websites ids and get the rule website id from this table in the database catalogrule_group_website and from this table catalogrule_website ( paste them here so we can match if the store ID assigned is correct or no ? )

Comment: Okay, so I compared the tables. In catalogrule_group_website we have: `rule_id`,`customer_group_id`,`website_id`.  In catalogrule_website we have `rule_id` and `website_id`. I attempted to add `customer_group_id` to see if that would fix it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, as far as values, in `catalogrule_website` we have `rule_id` = 7 and `website_id` = 1. In `catalogrule_group_website` there are no rows.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the patches which you migrated to magento community. I hope someting miss coded. Some kind of Array printed during executing code.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9332922#9332922

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when migrated fro 1.5.1.0 to 1.7.0.2 Magento CE. The problem is with the columns "website_ids" and "customer_group_ids" of the catalogrule table. These columns don't exist in 1.7.0.2 database, but if you try to remove them from a migrated Magento store you will not be able to save any rule. The solution I found is that I assigned NULL value directly in the database for these two columns and afterwards the Apply Rule button worked. However, you need to repeat that job if you save again the rule.